# Is there any method for distinguishing a record of an association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, class, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, comparison

I'm looking for a method, with Rails, for distinguishing one record (ex: @user) of an association(ex: @users).

Here is what I'm trying to do :

```
def my_method(var)
  if var == #record
    # do something
  elsif var == #association
    #do something else
  end
end
```

`var` can be any record or association like @user, @users, @page, @pages, ...

I tried to solve this with .class or .each method without success ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A record is normally an instance of `ActiveRecord` base, an association is normally an enumerable collection.

You can explicitly check the type

```
def my_method(var)
  if var.is_a? ActiveRecord::Base
    # single instance
  else
    # collection, association
  end
end
```

or rely on Ruby duck-tying.

```
def my_method(var)
  if var.respond_to? :each
    # collection, association
  else
    # single instance
  end
end
```

Duck-typing is normally the preferred approach.